# Spring Boot Starter Web Dependency giving error of missing artifacts

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

When I add Spring Boot Starter Web dependency, it gives error of missing artifacts

When I remove the web dependency, the project runs, but I want the web dependency as well for my project.

Below is my POM.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>firstproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>firstproject</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        </project>
```

Below is the error list:
[image: This is the list of errors I am facing]
[image: Error message while running mvn clean install]

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error image link @SujayMohan

Comment: Are you using any proxy for connecting to maven repo?

Comment: Perform a mvn clean install

Comment: It seems your mvn install got interrupted, go to folder .m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/{Spring boot version}

and delete the folder then perform  mvn clean install

Comment: update the dependency forcefully to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes, we are using a company's proxy @SujayMohan

Comment: mvn clean install giving error after performing the following steps as mentioned @Shailesh

Comment: we have also tried updating it forcefully, but its not working @DhrumilShah

Comment: @AtulAgrawal Please check the proxy configuration present in your maven conf folder. verify you are able to access the maven repo using the same proxy config.

Comment: While opening the **conf** folder, there are settings.xml, toolchains.xml and **logging** folder. We have checked the contents, but I am not able to recognize the proxy configurations in that. Would you please help me with that.

Comment: I have updtaed the question with the image of error given by mvn clean install command. Please have a look @Shailesh

Comment: I have updtaed the question with the image of error given by mvn clean install command. Please have a look @Rohit

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me couple of times, When I changed the spring boot version.

> Whenever you change the spring boot version all dependency gets downloaded from internet and sometime few jar files download gets corrupted or incomplete , however since jar is still there  in your .m2 folder, maven doesn't correct it. However your mvn install fails because it can't read jar.
>
> In order to solve this problem there are two ways

1. Navigate to your .m2 folder and locate the jars and delete it also delete m2e-lastUpdated.properties file and run mvn clean install
2. You can change your M2_HOME to different location and execute mvn clean install

In your current case, build is failing for hibernate validator jar, so delete same and run mvn clean install but your problem will not end , you might find another jar which is corrupted.

Repeat the process for all jars

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Maven could not able to download dependencies from Central Repository.
You can try adding `pluginRepository` after your `build` tag.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And replace

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

with

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Does it require any other changes in code? I have implemented the mentioned one, but it was giving the same errors @Im_Pratik

Comment: Please mention the stacktrace of the exception you're getting