# Maven Dependency shows error in springboot application

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to build RestAPI and for testing purpose, I am using h2 database so. I am working on STS, when i create the project it always shows exclamation sign in Maven Dependencies.

it says **Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE from https://repo.spring.io/libs-release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-libs-release has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE from/to spring-libs-release (https://repo.spring.io/libs-release): The operation was cancelled.**

*It is happening for a lot of jars, I am not sure what that is, Any help would be appreciated. :)*

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need to use a specific repository for the one getting you an error: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.2.1.RELEASE/jar
Retry with mvn -U or remove the the "latest update" file in the M2_REPO directory.

Comment: sounds like mvn install got interrupted either by network speed or for some other reason
read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075055/spring-boot-starter-web-dependency-giving-error-of-missing-artifacts/58079162#58079162

Comment: Thanks to all, The issue is resolved now after changing the version of My Project.